# programmatically read training output from cloud ml-engine

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

I run a job on `Cloud ML Engine` with `hyperparameter tuning`.

On the `Job details` page I can see the `trials` and `finalMetric` of each trial in the  `Training output` section in `JSON` format.

I wonder if I can download/read the `Training output` in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call the API using the python api client.

There is an example of that here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/python-guide#putting_it_all_together

You'll need to use the [ml.projects().jobs().get()](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/get) method.